# Chromium can't reach site when i am connected to my wifi network

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, ethernet-port

Yesterday i got my Raspberry Pi 3 model B and I have internet problem. I have Ethernet cable to my computer (mac) and I use my mac as a router. Everything works fine on my phone, but when i connected my RPi chromium show an error "This site can’t be reached (ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED)" to all pages. But it's not wifi problem beacuse i connected the same cable into RPi the same error ocurs.

Hopefully I can connect my RPi to internet throught my smartphone: phone is connected by Wi-Fi and to RPi by usb cable, then I turn on sharing by USB. So I upgraded software to latest version.

Please talk clearly and tell me what i have to do, because I have 14 years :)

This is `ifconfig` when i am connected to Wifi:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:97:57:e6  
      inet6 addr: fe80::11be:9dac:f7f9:e058/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1524 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1524 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:122928 (120.0 KiB)  TX bytes:122928 (120.0 KiB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:c2:02:b3  
      inet addr:169.254.212.12  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::7961:7e92:5b57:1cac/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2437 errors:0 dropped:2132 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:99 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:597394 (583.3 KiB)  TX bytes:25236 (24.6 KiB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wifi isn't connected, ip 169.254.212.12 is not valid address. Do you have DHCP serwer in this network? Is it running and MAC of Raspberry is configured? If not then assign proper ip address by editing file **/etc/network/interfaces** and setting something like this:

```
iface vlan0 inet static
address 192.168.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: That's not woking :(. I don't know how to check if have DHCP in my network. Also how to check if MAC if Raspberry is configured

Comment: But in my opinion the problem has nothing with my wifi because when I use ethernet port it also doesn't work

Comment: DO NOT advise people to put static in `/etc/network/interfaces` unless you are also going to tell them how to make it work by disabling `dhcpcd`.

Comment: @Milliways isn't that obvious that he need to replace existing configuration?

Comment: @Wojtek because on eth0 you probably also don't have proper ip configured either by static or dhcp server

Comment: This answer does not take into account that the IP range may be something else than 192.168._0_. So, all the devices on the network need to share every bit of the IP configuration except the last block of IP.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have the Pi directly connected to the Mac but have obviously not configured the Mac `ICS` correctly to allocate IP address, as the Pi is using a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address).

Even if you sort this out you **WILL NOT** be able to both access the Pi from the Mac **AND** access internet from the Pi. Nothing you can go on the Pi is going to change this (although advanced setup on the Mac to set up a bridge is possible).

If you have a router connect the Pi to this (via Ethernet or WiFi).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on one of my Raspberry Pi 4Bs after I made the IP address static. The following command resolves the issue for me, though you might have to re-execute this every time you turn on the Pi, so hopefully someone can find a better solution:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off             # set power management off
```

Comment: If you had made the Pi have a static IP by editing dhcpcd.conf add `static domain_name_servers=x.x.x.x y.y.y.y` under the interface and that will address your issue.

Comment: Power management is already disabled since years with Raspbian. You can find associated messages in `journalctl`.